# Floppy drive for both 3.5 and 5.25

Tags: floppy

The title is the question, I want to know if there is a floppy drive that can take, read, and write to both a 5.25 and 3.5 floppy disks.

Comment: The spindle speeds for 3.5" and 5.25" floppy drives are different, so you actually end up with two compact drives squished into the half-height form-factor.  (Who's old enough here to remember "full-height" drives?)

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is the best place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

There were combo drives that included both in one 5.25 case.
Like this: [image]

They're definitely refurbished or NOS (new old stock) now and you'd be hard pressed to find a motherboard with the necessary ports to connect both.  5.25" floppy cable connections disappeared about the time the Pentium 4 did.

You could, in theory, make your own if you had a combo drive.
You can get a 3.5" to USB, like this: 
34pin 1.44mb 3.5" floppy connector to USB cable adapter PCB board  (**the only place I can find these is on eBay, there are multiple sellers**)
https://www.ebay.com/itm/34pin-1-44mb-3-5-floppy-connector-to-USB-cable-adapter-PCB-board-/173354114412

And a 5.25" to USB like this:

FC5025 
http://www.deviceside.com/fc5025.html

Comment: Would there be a USB version of one? Anywhere

Comment: You'd need to make your own from an existing drive and use controllers like this: http://www.deviceside.com/.  There may be something similar for 3.5 side.

Comment: Would there be any reason to get a 5.25 floppy drive. Or should a 3.5 work for everything? I'm assuming anything the 5.25 was used for could be replaced with a 3.5.

Comment: If you have old 5.25 floppy disks you'd need to have a drive for that.  What's your use case?  If you don't have any floppies, you really don't need the drive.

Comment: I like to try out old operating systems. They only run off of floppys. Basically, I'm a computer historian

Comment: I'd convert my floppies to images via WinImage (http://www.winimage.com/winimage.htm) and then use something like VirtualBox.  Worth looking into.  You may also find pre-created floppy images in the public domain if the the OS is old enough.

Comment: *"I like to try out old operating systems. They only run off of floppys."* -- If such an *"old operating system"* is on floppy disk (e.g. CP/M or MS-DOS), then your plan simply will not work unless you can find some kind of emulator or virtual machine.  Those *"old operating systems"* predate USB, and will not operate any USB devices.  A floppy drive with a USB interface is for a current OS that has a USB stack and a proper driver for accessing floppy media.

Comment: Warning, that 5.25" USB adapter from deviceside.com is read-only.

Comment: As in really old Linux distributions

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Teac](https://books.google.com/books?id=0HJN4wxEVI4C&pg=PA318&dq=dual%20media%20floppy%20drive%203.5%205.25%20Teac&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi80ITo6sDeAhXpIDQIHUeLCbYQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=dual%20media%20floppy%20drive%203.5%205.25%20Teac&f=false) made [one such drive](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61f-wsocWQL._SX425_.jpg), and I recall others.

[image: Teac dual media flpoppy drive]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why someone down voted both answers...

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/